# Variable not looping properly

Tags: javascript

My program is supposed to take in an unknown amount of numbers and calculate the average to see if its >49 or <50. The problem occurs in the for loop. My sum isn't adding each mark and returns an undefined value. I have no idea why this is happening because the actual marks passes through the loop perfectly fine

```
var passingAverage = function ()
{

  var sum;
  var marks = arguments;
  var average;
  var i;
  for (i =0; i<marks.length; i++)
    {
      sum += marks.length[i];
    } 
      average = (sum/i);

      if (average > 49)
        {
          return ("true");
        }
      else if (average < 50)
        {
          return ("false");
        }

    };

console.log('passingAverage(75,42,98) returns: ' +   passingAverage(75,42,98));
console.log('passingAverage(34,93,77,89,49) returns: ' +     passingAverage(34,93,77,89,49));
console.log('passingAverage(33,61) returns: ' + passingAverage(33,61));
```

console.log("\n");

Comment: Write marks[i] instead of marks.length[i]

Comment: `return ("true");` seems weird, reason you are returning a string and not a boolean. It should just be `return true;`

Answer (score 0):

```
sum += marks.length[i];
```

this is not the true way of calling an array elements

replace `sum += marks.length[i];` with `sum += marks[i];` , then the true `sum` gonna be calculated , and your average has a true value

be **aware** of the **initial value** of `sum` when you are defining it , it must be `var sum = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initalise sum. change var sum to var sum = 0;

Answer (score 0):

I've got the running code here: https://jsfiddle.net/bwcpps1v/

```
var passingAverage = function ()
{
  var sum = 0;
  var marks = Array.from(arguments);
  var average;
  var i;

  for (i =0; i<marks.length; i++)
  {
    sum += marks[i];
  } 

  average = (sum/marks.length);

  if (average > 49)
  {
    return true;
  } else if (average < 50) {
    return false;
  }

};

console.log('passingAverage(75,42,98) returns: ' +   passingAverage(75,42,98));
console.log('passingAverage(34,93,77,89,49) returns: ' +     passingAverage(34,93,77,89,49));
console.log('passingAverage(33,61) returns: ' + passingAverage(33,61));
```

A few observations:

- You need to get better at debugging. Learn about Chrome Dev tools as a start to debugging JS. Step through your source watching key vars and you would have caught the earliest error faster.
- Spend some time with a linter and also, indenting your code right using an IDE or decent text editor - it makes it easier to read and debug.

Comment: Good luck! If the answers you've gotten here worked for you, please upvote and/or mark correct to close out this question. That's the convention here in StackOverflow.